# Travel across Iran by train

Tags: trains, iran

I decided to travel to Iran and use the train for going to different cities there.
For booking tickets, would you recommend local websites or international ones?

Answer (score 12):

As usual the man in Seat 61 has some useful advice on his page for Iran

https://www.seat61.com/Iran.htm

Specific advice about buying tickets for travel within Iran is contained further down the page.

https://www.seat61.com/Iran.htm#Train%20travel%20within%20Iran

The best option seems to be to buy from alocal travel agency in Iran as the online sources have had mixed reviews. buying at the station is possible but you may need to buy several days in advance.

If you make the trip I am sure he would welcome feedback as it is still a difficult destination for many travellers outside organised tours.

Comment: All the useful information is behind links now. Would you mind adding excerpts to your answer?

Comment: @Mast Added some more info about the specific question.

Answer (score 6):

Local person here.

In here we prefer to buy tickets from our local websites because you can get huge discounts from them.

Websites we trust with PROS/CONS is:

https://www.alibaba.ir  ( Lack of English site but they have good support )

https://www.raja.ir/ ( its the official website to buy ticket but still lack of English website )

If your looking for Charter (discounted) trains go to https://www.tcharter.ir/en#!all, they have English website too.

There is a lot of websites in here for selling those tickets but not trust-able.

Comment: I love how raja.ir has a link at the top that says “English”, but when you click on it, it just reloads the Farsi version with no change. Brilliant strategy. :-D

Comment: (+1) do you want to send a link to this to the Man in Seat 61 in case he wants to add it to his page? I can do it if you prefer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet if you look carefully, after clicking "English", the language of the *site navigation* changes to English. But it's the only thing that does :-)

Comment: @AaronF Ah yes, so it does. Much more useful, of course – this way you know what it is you don’t understand. Known unknowns > unknown unknowns.

Answer (score 4):

You're providing very little context for your trip, so, I'm making the assumption that you're reasonably flexible and don't have a specific itinerary in mind.

If that's correct, in your position, I would buy tickets locally, in-country. It's easy, as cheap as it gets, and allows you to change your plans as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is advised to buy tickets before you travel.

From [Trip Advisor:](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293998-i9139-k10078689-Buy_Iran_train_ticket_at_station-Iran.html)

> I suggest you booking train ticket by some travel agencies!

Even though it is unofficial, [this site](http://www.iranrail.net/index.php) has been recommended by quite a few users.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your information. I have recently found that website http://iranrails.com a very useful and reliable site for buying train tickets of Iran railways.

Comment: it's not usable for global transfer. it works just in iran if you want to go from one city to another.